# "A [house made] of bricks" - a noun (house) before an adjective (made)?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Why can't I say "A **made house** of bricks", but "a **house made** of bricks"?
I've never asked someone about that. Does it has anything to do with **attributive adjectives**?

Another example:
"I saw three **kids happy** enough to jump up and down with glee.", but not "I saw three **happy kids** enough to jump up and down with glee".

I tried my best to find any topic about that in the internet. I'm sorry if my topic is duplicate.

Thank you!

Comment: @mahmudkoya No, there is no ellipsis.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  “made of bricks” is a simple participial phrase, qualifying “house”.  Similarly, “happy enough to jump up and down with glee” is an adjectival phrase qualifying “kids”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, adjectives or participles with postmodifying phrases cannot appear before a noun in English (we don't say things like *"a made of bricks house", or even "a made-of-bricks house"), and you can't just put the adjective before and the postmodifying phrase after (as in your example "a made house of bricks", which is not an acceptable way to express "a house made of bricks").

Comment: Is 'We don't do X' a reasonable reply to 'Why don't we do X?' on ELU, especially when no supporting evidence is offered? And what about 'This suit is made to measure'?